# Symfony VichUploaderBundle autowiring on DownloadHandler in a controller

Tags: symfony, vichuploaderbundle, hashids

I'm using Symfony 4 with VichUploaderBundle 1.9 and I'm having hard time injecting the `DownloadHandler` service in my controller in order to send file to the client.

I'm also using [HashidsBundle](https://github.com/roukmoute/HashidsBundle) in order to convert my entity ID to something like `jFaJ` in my URLs.

As stated in the [VichUploaderBundle documentation](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/downloads/serving_files_with_a_controller.md), I'm injecting the service in my controller like this :

```php
    public function download(Wallpaper $wallpaper, DownloadHandler $downloadHandler)
    {
        return $downloadHandler->downloadObject($wallpaper->getMedia(), 'uploadedFile');
    }
```

Here is the error I'm having:

> Argument 2 passed to App\Controller\WallpapersController::download()
>   must be an instance of Vich\UploaderBundle\Handler\DownloadHandler,
>   integer given, called in
>   /mnt/c/Users/user/Documents/Dev/symfony/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php
>   on line 151

I also tried to manually call the service by adding the following line in my controller:
`$this->get('vich_uploader.download_handler');`

But it's still not working, I have this error now:

> Service "vich_uploader.download_handler" not found: even though it exists in the app's container, the container inside "App\Controller\WallpapersController" is a smaller service locator that only knows about the "doctrine", "form.factory", "http_kernel", "parameter_bag", "request_stack", "router", "security.authorization_checker", "security.csrf.token_manager", "security.token_storage", "serializer", "session" and "twig" services. Try using dependency injection instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can return the file using BinaryFileResponse.

```
    public function download(Wallpaper $wallpaper): BinaryFileResponse
    {
        $file = new BinaryFileResponse($wallpaper->getMedia());
        return $file;
    }
```

For more info, check 
https://github.com/aythanztdev/prbtcnccd/blob/master/src/Controller/MediaObject/ShowMediaObjectAction.php

Comment: Thank you but this is a just a workaround. The issue is that Symfony is not able to properly autowire the DownloadHandler service. Anyway, I noticed that the problem *might* come from the HashidsBundle (which I forgot to mention when writing my question) and I opened an issue on their GitHub repository. One of the mainteners is currently looking into it and I will post the fix there if there is any. https://github.com/roukmoute/HashidsBundle/issues/8

Comment: Turns out that this is a bug with another library I'm using (HashidsBundle). https://github.com/roukmoute/HashidsBundle/issues/8